# TensorFlow | Store gradient in-between runs

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

For illustration purposes, suppose I have a simple LSTM network and an input sequence `X = (X1, ..., XT)`

```
input Xt = (x1,...,xn) --> [LSTM] --> [output_layer] --> output(y1,...,yk)
```

Is there a way I can feed the network individual timestep inputs and then invoke the training_op at the end? A pseudocode of what I want to achieve:

```
# Define computational graph
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, num_features])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, output_size])
lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, lstm.state_size])
lstm_output, state = lstm(x, state)
output = tf.nn.dense(lstm_output, units=units)
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, output)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)

# Train loop
with tf.Session() as sess:
  for batch in batches:
    state = np.zeros(...)
    for timestep in batch:
      feed_dict = construct_feed_dict(timestep, state)
      out, _ = sess.run([output, loss], feed_dict)
      # Defer the weight update until the end of sequence
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=???)
```

My understanding is, that the returned values are basic numpy arrays and therefore if I later again fed them to the network as part of the input the information about the computation of that value is lost.

I am well aware I can feed the input in the shape [total_timesteps, batch_size, num_features]. However I've found myself in situations where I couldn't adopt this approach:
1) The next timestep input is created from the network output `f(y_t-1)`.
2) Hidden state of LSTM cell is being fed as input to another layer at each timestep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully achieved this by implementing my own [`raw_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/nn/raw_rnn) cell.